# Did Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Break Constructor Attributes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, attributes, c++14

In VS2015u2 the following code compiled fine.

```
class Foo {
public:
   [[deprecated]] Foo(std::string);
   Foo();
};
```

Under VS2015u3, I am getting an error:

```
C2416: attribute 'deprecated' cannot be applied in this context
```

This works in GCC 5.2 and it worked in earlier versions of VS2015.  Granted, the deprecated attribute did not actually trigger a warning in VS2015, but that was not a significant concern.

Am I misunderstanding how to apply attributes to constructors?  Or is VS2015u3 broken in this regard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it shortly: Yes.

This is a bug wherein `deprecated` is allowed to be applied to the definition, but not to the declaration, of a constructor (other member functions seem fine). E.g. the following compiles cleanly, and unlike with Update 2, behaves correctly (yielding a [C4996 diagnostic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx)):

```
class Foo {
public:
    [[deprecated]] Foo(std::string) { }
    Foo() { }
};
```

Please submit a bug report to [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post back here with a link so that we may upvote it. :-]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and added detail.  Bug report here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2931827